# Regex for all spaces before a number

Tags: regex

I need to select via RegEx every space before a number.

I know whitespace is \s and digit is \d, but I can't figure out how to just grab the space before the number.

Sample text:
John Doe 6
Jane Doe 0

It should select the spaces before 6 and 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Grabbing a space?(space is space) if you want to test a number is present in a string then just use `\d`.

Comment: Is regex dependent on language? Javascript

Comment: Yes, it is.  There are slight differences, though they are typically with the more advanced Syntaxes.  For your requirement, I +1'd Denomales' answer.  But I'd be curious to know your end-goal.  I bet a better regex could accomplish what you actually need better.  Just tell us what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This regex will capture the space before any number

```
\s+(?=\d)
```

The positive look ahead `(?=\d)` requires that any number of whitespace characters be followed by a digit

If you want to match only spaces and not the other characters which could be represented by a `\s` then use:

```
[ ]+(?=\d)
```

Comment: I updated your answer.  A space in regex is the same as a space in this sentence, to separate.  If you are looking for a Space Character, use the Character-Class.  E.G.: [ ]+(?=\d).  Other than that, +1 for a good answer with options.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
(\s+)\d
```

It captures the spaces with the paretheses