# How to split a column having string and large amount(numeric) into 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a column which has some text and amount values and need to separate those. Something like: -
"Bank overdraft interest 18,465"

The code is in python. I tried regex, but it is splitting the the entire text and also the values separated by comma.

The code i used is: -

```
    for i in df['row_item']:
        strings = i
        print(re.findall(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', strings))
```

I treid the above code, but it is only splitting the numeric values and not giving the desired result.
the output should be something like: -
"Bank overdraft interest" "18,465"
Result I am getting: -
[('1', '8'), ('4', '65')]

Comment: Do all of the numeric values have commas, or are some like `53`,`127`,`6` and some like the sample posted? And do some have more than one comma like `11,234,567`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for all spaces before a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027952/regex-for-all-spaces-before-a-number)

Comment: Yes, all the values have commas and few have more than one comma.

Comment: Also, you can use [series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with the regex to split all rows in the column without using a loop

Comment: please see the pandas solution.

Answer (score 0):

`"Bank overdraft interest 18,465".rsplit(' ',1)` gives `['Bank overdraft interest', '18,465']`. You'll run into problems if there are spaces within the numeric part, however.

Comment: It is working for the numerical part, but it is also separating the text, ['3) Finance ', 'costs']

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the last line with:

`print(re.findall('([\D]+)([\d\,]+)',strings))`

I note that you are probably from continental Europe because you use ',' for decimal separator (ie half is 0,5).  Above code won't work when '.' used as decimal separator (ie 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

With pandas try Using regex should work for as follows:

### DataFrame Example:

```
>>> df
                              col
0  Bank overdraft interest 18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest 10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest 13,465
```

### Solution:

`str.extract()` with matched group one `(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)` for character set and another for `(\d+\,\d+)` digit match.

```
>>> df['col'].str.extract('(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+(\d+\,\d+)')
                         0       1
0  Bank overdraft interest  18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest  10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest  13,465
```

As it by default assigns the columns names as `0`  `1` and so on,  hence you could rename them on the fly as your desired column name with `DataFrame.rename()` .

```
>>> df['col'].str.extract('(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+(\d+\,\d+)').rename(columns={0:'col1', 1:'col2'})
                      col1    col2
0  Bank overdraft interest  18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest  10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest  13,465
```

Other Situation, in case you are looking only to extract the `numeric` values / get the new DataFrame with numeric values or Just want to assign a extra numeric column to extracted and added to same DataFrame then try below..

Extracting only `numeric` values from the DataFrame column.

```
>>> df['col'].str.extract('(\d+\,\d+)')
0    18,465
1    10,465
2    13,465
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Extracting `numeric` values and assigning back the to column `num_col` into the same DataFrame.

```
>>> df = df.assign(num_col=df['col'].str.extract('(\d+\,\d+)'))
>>> df 
                              col num_col
0  Bank overdraft interest 18,465  18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest 10,465  10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest 13,465  13,465
```

OR

```
>>> df['num_call'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+\,\d+)')
```

In case you want to see only `num_col` which we extracted then we can use follows..

```
>>> del df['col']
>>> df
  num_call
0   18,465
1   10,465
2   13,465
```

Another trick using named groups will become column names itself in the result.

See the documentation [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
>>> df.col.str.extract('(?P<string_col>\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+(?P<numeric_col>\d+\,\d+)', expand=True)
                string_col numeric_col
0  Bank overdraft interest      18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest      10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest      13,465
```

OR

```
>>> df.col.str.extract('(?P<string_col>\D+)\s+(?P<numeric_col>\d+\,\d+)', expand=True)
                string_col numeric_col
0  Bank overdraft interest      18,465
1  Bank overdraft interest      10,465
2  Bank overdraft interest      13,465
```